# c++ pass std::source_location::function_name() as string literal template argument

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have this code which returns modified function name string provided by `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro at compile time:

```
template<size_t N>
struct SL
{
    char value[N];
    constexpr SL(const char (&str)[N])
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
            value[i] = str[i];
    }
};

template<SL literal>
consteval auto PrettifyFunctionName()
{
    ...
}
```

I use it like this:

```
constexpr auto resultName = PrettifyFunctionName<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__>();
```

I'd like to replace the macro `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with [`std::source_location::function_name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/function_name)
How can I pass it as the template argument?
Is there another way to get it as `constexpr` value in PrettifyFunctionName?

Comment: `const char*` is not a valid template parameter type. However you should be able make a function `constexpr auto PrettifyFunctionName(const char* function_name)`

Comment: Alternatively: `consteval auto PrettifyFunctionName(std::source_location)` with `constexpr auto resultName = PrettifyFunctionName(std::source_location::current());`.

Comment: @Jarod42 source location functions **must** have `= std::source_location::current()` as the default value for their argument. That's how the magic works.

Comment: @Red.Wave, While I'd recommend that approach, the only magic is really that you can't implement `std::source_location` without compiler hooks. The defaulted argument thing simply relies on the pre-existing language rule that the default is evaluated at the callsite, so making the argument explicit does the same thing.

Comment: @chris take a look at implementation of  `current()`. Guess what: that too, relies on default arguments. Because too much compiler magic is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to `SL` that copies from a `const char*` into the array exactly as your current loop does and then:

```
constexpr auto funcName = std::source_location::current().function_name();
constexpr auto resultName = PrettifyFunctionName<SL<mystrlen(funcName)+1>(funcName)>();
```

You will need to define `mystrlen` equivalently to `strlen` yourself, because `std::strlen` is not marked `constexpr`.

It is not possible to avoid naming `funcName` twice, because its type doesn't contain information about its length and it isn't specified whether or not the result of `function_name` refers to a string literal. If it refers to a string literal, then it can't be passed directly as a template argument.

You could however replace `mystrlen(funcName)+1` with some sufficiently large number. It will then fail to compile if the actual function name is too long.

It may be easier to pass the string as function argument instead of template argument, assuming you don't need the string to be part of the type of `resultName` later on.

---

I think compile-time use of `source_location` isn't specified well btw.

The member functions are marked `constexpr` indicating that they should be usable at compile-time, but the result of `function_name` is only specified to refer to some null-terminated byte string.

It doesn't say whether that string is supposed to have static storage duration so that the pointer can be stored in a `constexpr` variable, whether it may refer to a string literal, so that it can't be used as template argument directly, and whether its elements are *usable in constant expressions*, so that the actual contents of the string can be inspected in constant expressions. (Although the first one kind of follows from `current` being marked `consteval`.)

But it is a general issue that library functions marked `constexpr` lack precise specification of which compile-time use is guaranteed and which is not.

Comment: Jason Turner has a long video on the problem of getting a const char* with length together in compile time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABg4_EV5L3w (not saying that your approach is wrong, just adding extra fluff for anyone interested in the problem)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I haven't watched that yet, but will do so later. There are a few more tricks one can apply to get this to look nicer, but for this use case there are also extra constraints in that the string must be obtained from a `source_location` call in exactly this function, not e.g. in a lambda.